# Set ImageView max height using code

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I want to set `Max Height` to `Imageview` that it can have when the image is loaded. Initial I've set `android:height="wrap_content"` in `XML` to make room for other views. But after the image is loaded sometimes it covers the whole screen of mobile and i can't see other views and i want to limit the height to some certain value. Please!! any help is appreciated.. cheers

Comment: You can change its size programatically. Should I give an example?

Comment: I've changed my layouts size pragmatically but haven't tried to change imageview size..

Comment: `imageview.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, YOUR_HEIGHT));`

Comment: @AshishGaurav examples are always welcome.. :)

Comment: @Sunny I can change layout size, i want to change ImageView size now.. this code gives error if applied to imageview

Answer (score 2):

> A structure describing general information about a display, such as
>   its size, density, and font scaling.

```
     DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        int DeviceTotalWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        int DeviceTotalHeight = metrics.heightPixels;


       /*
        *
        * Adding  Height Respect To Device
        * */

     ImageView  ImageViewObj=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageViewId);
     ImageViewObj.getLayoutParams().height= (int) (DeviceTotalHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the screen height, and use it to set some ratio like Sunny said.

```
/* get the screen height in pixels */
public static int getScreenHeight(WindowManager windowManager) {
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point point = new Point();
    display.getSize(point);
    return point.y;
}
/* take an imageview, and set its height to desired float ratio */
public static void setImageHeight(Activity activity, ImageView imageView, float ratio) {
    int h = getScreenHeight(activity.getWindowManager());
    imageView.getLayoutParams().height = (int)(h*ratio);
}
```

Then in `onCreate(....)`, try doing

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.whatever);
setImageHeight(imageView, 0.4f); /* 40% */
```